# Вызов функции из DLL

Tags: c#

Импортирую библиотеку в *C#* и получаю:

> unable to find entrypoint.

Что делаю не так?

Список функций библиотеки:

[image: Функции бибиотеки]

Код импорта:

```
[DllImport("xxx.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

public static extern int ReadDomainPassword(string user, string domain, StringBuilder password);
```

Comment: «и получаю - unable to find entrypoint» — что значит «получаю»? Ошибка компиляции? Исключение? Текст в логе? Объясните нормально, вы ж программист.

Comment: Может у нее там действительно беда с точкой входа?

Comment: да какой я программист если такие вопросы задаю :) исключение это EntryPointNotFoundException если быть точнее

Comment: и как выяснить есть ли проблема с точкой входа? вроде библиотека используется повседневно, только я с ней первый раз сталкиваюсь...

Comment: А вот так работает: [DllImport("xxx.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?ReadDomainPassword@@YAHPAD00@Z")] выходит это name mangling не учитывается в программе изображение из которой я приложил. Пользовался Dependency Walker там оказалось полное название функции... Только остается вопрос - возможно ли не писать entrypoint а использовать другую директиву?

Comment: @AlexShawnee это потому что у вас библиотека C++, а не C. В C нет name mangling. А в C++ нужно `extern "C"` прописывать чтобы нормально экспортилось по именам.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin А как же тогда быть если у меня нет доступа к исходникам этой библиотеки? Использовать Dependency Walker каждый раз чтобы выяснить полное название функции? Или есть обходной вариант?

Comment: @AlexShawnee ммм.. тут конечно мне на 100% верить нельзя, не эксперт, но думаю вариантов 2, написать враппер используя `GetProcAddress` но это довольно много работы (но этим вы защититесь от изменений версии DLL). Если же ваша длл не меняется то можно обойтись и тупо прописывать полное имя с mangling.

Comment: Если найдено решение,  пожалуйста, опубликуйте его в ответе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При импорте следует использовать имя функции созданное компилятором:

```
[DllImport("xxx.dll", EntryPoint="?ReadDomainPassword@@YAHPAD00@Z", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Как я понял это наиболее простой вариант. 
P.S.: посмотреть имя функции C++ можно через DLL Export Viewer или Dependency Walker, только чтобы не оказаться в такой же ситуации как и я - снимайте галку Undecorate C++ functions в DLL Export Viewer, иначе будете видеть "правильное" имя по которому получите *EntryPointNotFoundException*